# Nested filter returns wrong result when Object name is not given to search

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elastic search, I am trying to get data for nested object

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
NestedQueryBuilder nestedBuilder =      QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("Attributes", boolBuilder);
boolBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("Attributes.attributeId", "1001"));
```

Result comes if the query is like this,

```
 {
  "nested" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "term" : {
            "Attributes.attributeId" : "1001"
          }
         ]
      }
    },
   "path" : "Attributes"
  }'
```

Result not coming if the query is like this,

```
 {    
  "nested" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "term" : {
            "attributeId" : "1001"
          }
         ]
      }
    },
    "path" : "Attributes"
  }
```

Can somebody help me.Here i have to get result without using "**Attributes.attributeId**".ie. using "**attributeId**" alone data have to come.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected as per the nested query [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

> The query path points to the nested object path, and the query (or
>   filter) includes the query that will run on the nested docs matching
>   the direct path, and joining with the root parent docs. **Note that any
>   fields referenced inside the query must use the complete path (fully
>   qualified).**